# How could I use rmdir in SFTP to remove remote folders not empty?

Tags: sftp, sharpssh, rmdir

Recently, I'm using SharpSSH to deal with remote files. The SharpSSH offers API of `rmdir` for removing remote directories, but I find that it throws exceptions with message *"Permission denied"* when the directory is not empty. Then I've got to delete each file before the final `rmdir` recursively, which is not efficient.

So how could I use this `rmdir` without the fool recursive deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. In SFTP protocol, in general, there's no API to delete a folder recursively.

So even if you use another library that allows deleting a folder with a single call (like *my* WinSCP [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles)), it still internally has to recurse into subdirectories.

---

*Side note: Do not use SharpSSH, it's a dead project.*

Comment: So I've got to suffer my recursive work...Thanks anyway~